# Formatting pdf-output chunks of bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown

I'm tinkering with `bookdown` and am generating both html and pdf output.

For the html output the rendered `R` input and output are placed in blocks with gray background. For the pdf output the input chunks are highlighted but the output isn't. For example the following source code

````
Blah blah blah

```{r, message=FALSE}
library(mosaic)           # Load mosiac-pakken
tally(~ Smoke, data=fev)  # Optæl Smoke
```

Blah blah blah
````

results in this tex output:

```
\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\KeywordTok{library}\NormalTok{(mosaic)           }\CommentTok{# Load mosiac-pakken}
\KeywordTok{tally}\NormalTok{(}\OperatorTok{~}\StringTok{ }\NormalTok{Smoke, }\DataTypeTok{data=}\NormalTok{fev)  }\CommentTok{# Optæl Smoke}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\begin{verbatim}
Smoke
  0   1 
589  65 
\end{verbatim}
```

The input is wrapped in `Shaded` and `Highlighting` which can be modified in the preamble of the tex file. The output, however, is only wrapped in a standard `verbatim` environment which would be problematic to redefine in the file (since a redefinition will mess other parts up). How can I setup my configuration to wrap the output in an environment that I can redefine? Or possibly just keep the input and output wrapped in the same environment?

My `_output.yml` file looks like this (which is more or less copied from Yihui)

```
bookdown::pdf_book:
  highlight: zenburn
  includes:
    in_header: latex/preamble.tex
    before_body: latex/before_body.tex
    after_body: latex/after_body.tex
  keep_tex: yes
  dev: "cairo_pdf"
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
  template: null
  pandoc_args: --chapters
  toc_depth: 3
  toc_unnumbered: no
  toc_appendix: yes
  quote_footer: ["\\VA{", "}{}"]
```

How can I change the code to add a wrapper or just redefine the format of the output chunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [**bookdown** 0.4](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/releases/tag/v0.4), you can use a global option `bookdown.post.latex` to post-process the LaTeX output. In your case, it will be like:

```
options(bookdown.post.latex = function(x) {
  # x is the content of the LaTeX output file
  gsub('^\\\\(begin|end)\\{verbatim\\}$', '\\\\\\1{YOUR_ENVIRONMENT}', x)
})
```

Then define the custom environment in your LaTeX preamble.

Comment: Won't that will replace *all* verbatim environments? I just want to replace the output chunks and not other instances of the verbatim environment. For example raw text could be enclosed in ```  and I wouldn't want to use the same environment for that (although that could possibly be fixed by creating a custom block for that)

Comment: You are correct. I don't have a better solution then. THe challenge is that there is no way to designate a particular LaTeX environment to certain fenced code blocks in Pandoc's Markdown (otherwise you can just modify knitr's output hook and use a different type of fenced code blocks for text output from R chunks).